# Multiple route builders defined in single Camel context are sequential?

Tags: apache-camel

I wanted to understand how multiple routes in same camel context will behave?

For example, Let's say I have an application wherein I have a single camel context which contains three different **route builders** each defining one route. Each of these routes are listening to different queues.

Can someone please let me know if all these three routes will work in parallel or only one will process the message while others wait?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the queues will function in parallel. You can also specify the number of threads (.threads()) the route uses. So, with that it is safe to presume that the routes run in parallel.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I have seen one route processing the message while other waits even though messages are there.

Comment: Have you find how they work and how to schedule them to run in parallel?